# Getting Google Ads API keyword_plan_idea_error: The input has an invalid value

Tags: google-ads-api

```
$requestOptionalArgs = [];
$requestOptionalArgs['keywordSeed'] = new KeywordSeed(['keywords' => $keywords]);
$keywordPlanIdeaServiceClient->generateKeywordIdeas([
                                'language' => ResourceNames::forLanguageConstant(1000), // English
                                'customerId' => $customerId,
                                'geoTargetConstants' => $geoTargetConstants,
                                'keywordPlanNetwork' => KeywordPlanNetwork::GOOGLE_SEARCH
                            ] + $requestOptionalArgs);
```

The above code is working fine if the $keywords array size is not more than 20. If I add the 21st keyword to the $keywords array then it's throwing the below error.
`keyword_plan_idea_error: The input has an invalid value.`

Answer (score 0):

Google Ads API has a limit of 20 keywords per request. You'll need to separate your keywords into chunks and loop through them.

Something like this:

```
<?php

$keywords = [];

// Create multiple arrays to pass through Google Ads API
$chunk = array_chunk($keywords, 20, true);

foreach ($chunk as $piece) {

    $requestOptionalArgs = [];

    $requestOptionalArgs['keywordSeed'] = new KeywordSeed(['keywords' => $piece]);

    $keywordPlanIdeaServiceClient->generateKeywordIdeas([
         'language' => ResourceNames::forLanguageConstant(1000), // English
         'customerId' => $customerId,
         'geoTargetConstants' => $geoTargetConstants,
         'keywordPlanNetwork' => KeywordPlanNetwork::GOOGLE_SEARCH
    ] + $requestOptionalArgs);

}
```